# Diagnosing desktop computer that unexpectedly shuts down - not overheating

Tags: windows-7, cpu, power-supply, shutdown

Today my office desktop computer (which is also the main network machine) shut down unexpectedly while exporting a very large data file - the other computers in the network were already off. The moment this happened, the machine felt cool and the fans were not running remarkably fast. Nevertheless the computer was indeed "working hard" as other activity such as typing in a word file or dragging windows were lagging a bit before it shut down. When turning it on, the typical windows screen for incorrect shut down appeared, after that, it seems nothing else happened.

No hardware or recent software change was applied in the last month.

I would like to understand if there's anything wrong at software or (more likely unfortunately) hardware level and what's the best way to investigate it.
Or (best case scenario) if this is just a strange isolated PSU fail.

Fans stats with SpeedFan (when re-running the export procedure):
Primary Fan: 6618 RPM, temp. 60C; Secondary Fan: 5037 RPM, temp.33C, GPU: 50C.

Specs:
Processor: AMD A10-5800K APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics 3.80 GHz
RAM: 32 GB
SO: Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit
Age: probably around 4 years old.

Thank you very much in advance.

From Event Viewer Before Critical Kernel-Power error (when the computer shut down):

- (1 hour before the shut down) The shadow copies of volume C: were aborted because the shadow copy storage could not grow due to a user imposed limit. Source: volsnap, Event ID: 36.
- (multiple times 2 hours before the shut down) The following fatal alert was received: 40. Source: Schannel, EventID: 36887.

Further update: It turned off 2 more times since yesterday (yesterday evening and this morning, no events in the log in  the hours before the shut downs).

Comment: Is there dust on the CPU fan? If yes, please clean it off. Can you please edit your question with any important event logs recorded prior to the shutdown?

Comment: Thank you Nordlys Jeger, I will surely clean the CPU fan as I do not know when this was done last time... About the event viewer, I added some info in the question (I hope the info is sufficient, I am not familiar with this application so I am not sure what and how to report it, I only extracted the info that was in "Administrative Events." Summary page events only had the critical error of shut down.